# Как сделать такой background?

Tags: android, background

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Необходимо, чтобы задний фон обрезался по размеру текста и при этом плавно перетекал при переходе (см. углы)

*Скриншот взят из Instagram*

**UPD:** `BackgroundColorSpan` не подходит- в него нельзя загружать собственный `drawable`, а в реализации по-умолчанию у фона острые углы и нет переходов

Comment: Привет. Думаю здесь нужно созадать свой собственный елемент на основе (textview (нужен для нахождения мест разрыва строки, используется только для разбивая большой строки и не видим пользователю)  и listview (нужен для отображения)) в самом адаптере в зависимости от размеров следующей и предыдущей строки используешь один из 4 фонов для item. Возможно есть более оптимальное решение, но я пока его не вижу

Comment: А какие 4 фона? Если делать через shape, невозможно будет сделать закругленные углы наружу. Спасибо за предложение

Comment: 1. верхние и нижние угли внутрь
2. верхние и нижние угли наружу
3. верхние внутрь, нижние наружу 
4. верхние наружу, нижние внутрь. когда писал ответ я думал использовать 9.png изображения.

Comment: Доктор, а откуда у вас такие картинки? Из какого-то еще приложения, али сами нарисовали?

Comment: Скриншот из Instagram

Comment: А может с помощью css тень задать внешнюю непрозрачную?

Comment: css не знаю от слова совсем. Это можно использовать в android?

Comment: Придется смотреть ширину текста и закруглять через `*Radius`. Причем каждую строку, по отдельности или делать блоками.

Comment: Вопрос интересный ждем умников и умниц

Comment: Проще всего загнать в фотошоп это фото и сделать с помощью трех слоев, сперва черный потом серый ( его форму можно отредактировать с помощью выделения и заливки), а потом уже текст подобрать( в общем минут 30) !

Comment: Такой стиль текста уже обсуждалось вот ссылка : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792445/border-radius-like-instagram-stories

Comment: Не знаю точно, да и коментарии мне недоступны, но вроде бы я случайно добивался такого результата когда добавлял собственную разметку на textView, можно также через стиль сделать. Но если упороться то можно через размер текста добавить разметку с listview

Answer (score 1):

Если сильно надо то можно это сделать это через html документ. А потом запихнуть это все в webview.

Как сделать такой текст на html,css:
https://nisnom.com/veb-razrabotki/plavno-obtekayushhij-fon-teksta-s-pomoshhyu-svg/

Как это все запихнуть в webview:
https://youtu.be/Kufnu_q8MwA

Надеюсь это вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

[BackgroundColorSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html) изменяет фон текста

Comment: Носколько я знаю, при помощи BackgroundColorSpan нельзя выставить свой кастомный background, а обычный цвет здесь точно не подойдет